# GUI for managing services

Tags: java, service

I would like to create a Java APP that could register instances of a service and start/stop them. I don't want a GUI to be launched with the service, but a manager that can run separately to it and interact with the status of the server

Any pointers at where to start?

Comment: Windows services can not have any GUIs at all. You're service management GUI has to be a separate program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jcraft to SSH into your local host and call commands. If you do it this way it will take two hours to write. http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Also take a look at:
[In Java, send commands to another command-line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877609/in-java-send-commands-to-another-command-line-program)